# Does ◻(∀x)(Fx ⊃ ◻(E!x & (E!x ⊃ Fx))) entail ◻((∃x)Fx ⊃ ◻(∃x)Fx)?

Tags: modal-logic, free-logic

I was wondering if we can derive ◻((∃x)Fx ⊃ ◻(∃x)Fx) from ◻(∀x)(Fx ⊃ ◻(E!x & (E!x ⊃ Fx)))? (By the way 'E!' is the existence predicate.)

I am using the Quantified Free Modal Logic constructed/mentioned by Sobel, p.110f from his book Logic and Theism.

Comment: Isn’t that an obsolete symbol for implication, I’ve only seen it very old and out of date books. Existence, by the way, is *not* a predicate, even if it formally looks like one.

Comment: Before trying to answer, I would like to know what does the '!' denote here?

Comment: @SmootQ It's said it denotes existence predicate, but what's that? I know uniqueness quantifier, but quantifiers are not predicates themselves.

Comment: Ah, you mean this ∃!x , this is the first time I see E!x with E. Thank you

Comment: @SmootQ No, he does not mean ∃!x (that wouldn't be syntactically correct), E!x is the existence predicate from free logic. James McGraw, can you specify, which of the thousand semantics you are using? It is impossible to answer otherwise. Also, are we in S5? More input please.

Comment: I see, that is why I find it weird to use E!x without a proposition next to it as I thought it is just another ∃!x. I will do some research to know how can this E!x be treated and what inference rules are related to it, Thank you.

Comment: @JishinNoben I was thinking in terms of a variable domain semantics (ideally one that validates neither the Barcan nor the Converse Barcan). And, yes, S5. So any (standard) variable domain quantified S5 system that validates none of the Barcans.

Comment: @JishinNoben Would the Barcan and the Converse Barcan be valid in Sobel's FrMQMdlC if you happen to know? I tried working it out but couldn't exactly figure it out.

Comment: Both are invalid.

Comment: @JishinNoben So this is the kind of system I was in search for? A variable domain QS5 system that validates neither the Barcan nor the Converse Barcan in which the inference in my original post is a valid one?

Comment: It is a semantics which makes the inference valid. It might be easier to understand, if you transform the conclusion into the logically equivalent sentence  ◻¬∃xFx ∨ ◻∃xFx and for the premise the equivalent form ◻∀x(Fx → ◻(E!x ∧ Fx)).
The books presentation has btw one of the worst presentations of QML I have encountered. If you really want to understand the formal parts, choose another book.

Comment: @JishinNoben From what I recall -- and correct me if I'm mistaken -- in any constant domain quantified modal logic system the Barcan formula and the Converse Barcan formula are going to be valid (it is from the fact that they both are valid do we get a constant domain). So if at least one of them is invalid in any quantified modal logic system, then that system is a variable domain quantified modal logic system. In the case of Sobel's system since both of these formulas are invalid then it would be the case that his system is a variable domain quantified (free) modal logic system.

Answer (score 1):

@SmootQ Hello Smoot. I was trying to work on this problem on my own and I think I managed to come up with something. I'd appreciate it if you can let me know if I managed to do this correctly. (Thanks in advance.)

So the problem was to go from ☐(x)(Fx ⊃ ☐(E!x & (E!x ⊃ Fx))) to ☐((∃x)Fx ⊃ ☐(∃x)Fx). The thought was to use a variable domain (free) quantified modal logic S5 system. Here's what I have tried doing:

We start with our premise ☐(x)(Fx ⊃ ☐(E!x & (E!x ⊃ Fx))). From this we can straightforwardly deduce that ☐((∃x)Fx ⊃ (∃x)☐(E!x & (E!x ⊃ Fx))). Call this N. I will come back to this later. Now we assume the consequent of this, i.e. (∃x)☐(E!x & (E!x ⊃ Fx)), for conditional proof.

Conditional proof: So we start with (∃x)☐(E!x & (E!x ⊃ Fx)). From this we can straightforwardly deduce that (∃x)☐(E!x & Fx). At this point using the free logic rule for existential generalization (since we have E!x) we can deduce that (∃x)☐(∃x)Fx. Since the first (∃x) now becomes redundant we can move to ☐(∃x)Fx. That completes our conditional proof. From (∃x)☐(E!x & (E!x ⊃ Fx)) we have deduced that ☐(∃x)Fx. Hence we conclude that (∃x)☐(E!x & (E!x ⊃ Fx)) ⊃ ☐(∃x)Fx.

Since we used nothing more than the rules of our logic to establish this conditional above then by necessitation rule we can move to ☐((∃x)☐(E!x & (E!x ⊃ Fx)) ⊃ ☐(∃x)Fx). Call this N'. Now from N (from above) and N' we can by transitivity of strict implication move to our conclusion ☐((∃x)Fx ⊃ ☐(∃x)Fx).

So, then, we have successfully deduced ☐((∃x)Fx  ⊃ ☐(∃x)Fx) from our premise ☐(x)(Fx ⊃ ☐(E!x & (E!x ⊃ Fx))).

Comment: That's a clever one, assuming the consequent and deducing a conditional logical entailment from it, thank you for sharing! - I was struggling with this proof then I stopped trying for a while just to find time for some other stuff.. , the difficulty I found is in the 1st step in your proof : `(x)(Px ⊃ Qx) ∴ ((∃x)Px ⊃ (∃x)Qx)`, this inference rule did not occur to me. Thank you again. +1

Comment: Don't forget to check it as a best answer. ;)

Comment: Thank you for looking it over. Just one question I had, it seems S5 (or even S4 or B or T for that matter) wasn’t used in the proof. So then this would be a valid argument even in a variable domain (free) quantified modal logic K system?

Comment: yes I think so, since you only used basic inference rules in propositional and first order quantificational logic, of course you are allowed to use axioms in modal systems, but you don't have to.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is No! and here is the refutation :

> 1. ◻(∀x)(Fx ⊃ ◻(E!x & (E!x ⊃ Fx)))   **[the premise]**
>
>    2. ∴◻((∃x)Fx ⊃ ◻(∃x)Fx)    **[the conclusion]**
>    3. Assume:  ~◻((∃x)Fx ⊃ ◻(∃x)Fx)   **[we assume the opposite of 2]**
>    4. ∴ ◇~((∃x)Fx ⊃ ◻(∃x)Fx)  **[from 3, reverse squiggle]**
>    5. W ∴ ~((∃x)Fx ⊃ ◻(∃x)Fx)  **[from 4, we introduce a possible world W]**
>    6. W ∴ (∃x)Fx **[from 5, break not-if, antecedent true]**
>    7. W ∴ ~◻(∃x)Fx **[from 5, break not-if, consequent false]**
>    8. W ∴ ◇~(∃x)Fx  **[from 7, reverse squiggle]**
>    9. W ∴ Fa **[from 6, drop existential]**
>    10. W ∴  (∀x)(Fx ⊃ ◻(E!x & (E!x ⊃ Fx))) **[from 1, drop box]**
>    11. W ∴ (Fa ⊃ ◻(E!a & (E!a ⊃ Fa))) **[from 10, drop Universal]**
>    12. W ∴ (E!a & (E!a ⊃ Fa))  **[from 11 and 9, Modus ponens and drop box]**
>    13. W ∴ E!a   **[from 12, conjunction elimination]**
>    14. W ∴ (E!a ⊃ Fa)   **[from 12, conjunction elimination]**
>    15. W ∴ (∃y)(y=a)  **[from 13, according to E!x definition in reference below]**
>    16. W ∴ b=a   **[from 15, drop existential]**
>    17. W ∴ Fa  **[from 14 and 13, modus ponens]**
>    18. W ∴ Fb  **[from 17 and 16, identity]**

As you can see, although we have assumed the opposite of the conclusion and have all the propositions broken down, we could not obtain a contradiction.

So, it is possible for the premise **◻(∀x)(Fx ⊃ ◻(E!x & (E!x ⊃ Fx)))** to be true, 
while the conclusion **◻((∃x)Fx ⊃ ◻(∃x)Fx)** is false, in a possible world where a=b and where it is possible that no x is F (◇~(∃x)Fx)

Since we could not obtain a contradiction, it means that the premise does not entail the conclusion.

**Note:** I went from step 13 to 15 using the definition :

> **E!a := (∃x)(x=a)**

Reference : https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-free/#1.1

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Just a question-- so after digging around a bit I found something where someone shows that ◻(∀x)(Fx ⊃ ◻(E!x & Fx)) entails ◻((∃x)Fx ⊃ ◻(∃x)Fx). In our case we're using ◻(∀x)(Fx ⊃ ◻(E!x & (E!x ⊃ Fx))), which entails ◻(∀x)(Fx ⊃ ◻(E!x & Fx)), so shouldn't ◻(∀x)(Fx ⊃ ◻(E!x & (E!x ⊃ Fx))) entail ◻((∃x)Fx ⊃ ◻(∃x)Fx) then? The link below includes a picture of the proof where said person shows ◻(∀x)(Fx ⊃ ◻(E!x & Fx)) to entail ◻((∃x)Fx ⊃ ◻(∃x)Fx) (they use 'P' instead of 'F').

https://imgur.com/a/q1PhGwo

Comment: Really? I spent a lot of time trying to obtain a contradiction but I couldn't , and the best I could get was some atomic propositions that can't be broken further. I will look at the proof and see if I can find something, thanks for the share.

Comment: I am not sure of what he means by PERFnecEx&NecPerf in line 5 ? It would be great if I find the title of the book / paper.

Comment: After some search I found this , maybe it would help what PERFnecEx&NecPerf  means  : https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Andrew_Messing/post/How_to_define_God/attachment/59d64111c49f478072eaaa81/AS%3A273793950388227%401442288973363/download/Logic+And+Theism-+Arguments+For+And+Against+Beliefs+In+God.pdf 

There is something similar around page 87

Comment: So this is from a book on philosophy of religion. *PERFnecEx&NecPerf*:

◻(∀x)(Px ⊃ ◻(E!x & Px)).

Necessarily, anything that is a perfect being is necessarily existent and necessarily a perfect being.

He tries to show that this entails: ◻((∃x)Px ⊃ ◻(∃x)Px).

Necessarily, if there exists a perfect being, then necessarily there exists a perfect being.

Comment: Oh right, just checking the book you're looking at. It is from this book. On page 87 there is a similar principle that says ◻(∀x)◻(Px ⊃ ◻(E!x & Px)), which he also says entails AP (where AP is ◻((∃x)Px ⊃ ◻(∃x)Px)). Then on page 88 he considers the principle we're talking about ◻(∀x)(Px ⊃ ◻(E!x & Px)) and says that it entails AP as well. Page 113 is where the picture is from.

Comment: Yes, that's right , and I am no expert when it comes to the philosophy of religion, so maybe there is some kind of reasoning or inference rules that lead to these conclusions about modal necessity and perfect beings.  So  PERFnecEx&NecPerf stands for "Perfect Being + Necessity + Existentence  and Necessity + Perfect Being

Comment: Yes, it's on page 113

Comment: Shouldn't the proof he gives on page 113 work for any predicate? So for instance if we replace his 'P' with 'F' then we should be able to show that ◻(∀x)(Fx ⊃ ◻(E!x & Fx)) entails ◻((∃x)Fx ⊃ ◻(∃x)Fx), under the logical system he's considering which he explains a bit before page 113.

Comment: I don't really know, I will have to read some chapters from that book in order to follow, Using Modal Logic inference rule I would say that the premise does not entail the conclusion, but now I am curious to know exactly what is it all about.

Comment: Just to help you out a little bit so you don't waste time reading irrelevant philosophy of religion stuff: From pages 105 to 107 he explains a logical system that he calls "Sentential modal logic" (SMC for short). Then from pages 110 to 112 he explains a logical system (that is an extension of SMC) that he calls "Free Monadic Quantifier Modal Calculus" (FrMQMdlC for short). And finally on page 113 he shows ◻(∀x)(Px ⊃ ◻(E!x & Px)) to entail ◻((∃x)Px ⊃ ◻(∃x)Px) in FrMQMdlC.

Comment: Ah, I see, thank you ... so I will start from page 105 and read to page 113.

Comment: Basically but you don't have to read pages 108 and 109. In those pages he shows some derivations in the SMC system which are irrelevant.

Comment: Okay, thank you...  I will take some time to read.

Comment: Hey. I was wondering if you happened to work out whether it’s valid or not. Thanks.

Comment: @JamesMcGraw  Not yet,.. I will let you know once I find out.

Comment: Hey. I was posting a comment but it was too long to post it. I added it as an "answer" separately.